# Forçar o usuário a teclar enter

Tags: java, algoritmo-de-busca, arraylist

Em um trecho do meu codigo, preciso que o usuario tecle enter para entao continuar o programa, porem a parte onde deve receber esta entrada é ignorada.

```
public void buscar_Aluno(){ //metodo que busca um determinado aluno pelo nome
    String lerTeclado;

    String s = "";
    String nome_Aluno ;
    try{
        System.out.printf("Digite o nome do aluno:\t");
            nome_Aluno = sc.next();

        int indice = 0;
        for(Aluno ler : array){  //For para percorrer o vetor para procurar alunos com o mesmo nome
            if(ler.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(nome_Aluno)){ //Se o aluno possuir nome igual ao procurado, sera chamado o metodo toString
                Aluno l = array.get(indice);
                System.out.print(l.toString());
            }else { //Caso contrario, indice incrementa
                indice ++ ;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Tecle enter para continuar.\t"); //Esta parte é ignorada
        lerTeclado = sc.nextLine();

    }catch(InputMismatchException ex){
        System.out.print("Valor incorreto.\n");
        tela();
    }finally{
        tela();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mude o primeiro *sc.next()* onde você captura o nome do aluno, para *sc.nextLine()*

Assim deve funcionar.